Image size reduced when using a TabView
I am trying to build an app with a feed. The feed contains images and I am trying to add a carousel effect so when there is more than one image, the user can swipe left/right.
The code I have is showing the carousel as expect in the preview for the post itself but as soon as I am using it in the LazyVStack to display a feed, the images are smaller.
When I built Post itself, it works well with the code below:
struct FeedPostView: View {
    let post: Post
    @Binding var showNavBar: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: PostDetailsView(post: post, showNavBar: $showNavBar)) {
                    TabView {
                        ForEach(post.images.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                            Image(post.images[idx])
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .scaledToFill()
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 450)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0))
            .overlay(PostHeaderView(post: post), alignment: .top)
            .overlay(PostCaptionView(post: post), alignment: .bottom)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing])
        .padding(.bottom, 15)
        }
    }
}

and it looks like:

This is exactly what I am looking for.
But as soon as I check how it looks in the feed, it looks like:

it's really weird because the image height is reduced.
here is the code:
ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
                    ForEach(Post.MOCK_POSTS) { post in
                        FeedPostView(post: post, showNavBar: $showNavBar)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 10)
             }
            .navigationTitle("Feed")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

Any idea how to keep the image as show in the first image ?

Note, TabView should be the top most container, not inside a NavigationStack. Each Tab in the TabView would then have their own NavigationStack. TabView manages tabs for switching between views, while NavigationStack utilizes a hierarchy of views for navigation.
Consequently, the two would conflict in managing navigation.

Can you try below code if this works for you looks like you have applied lazy stack before loop so it might causing that issue.
ScrollView { 
    ForEach(Post.MOCK_POSTS) { post in
    LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
       FeedPostView(post: post, showNavBar: $showNavBar)
    }
    .padding(.top, 10 )

    }
}
.navigationTitle("Feed")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

